# How to create this type of element?

Tags: css, xhtml, layout, html

I want to create an element using `DIV` and CSS like below:

```
Create By: <avatar image 16x16> Prashant
```

Can anyone tell me what will be the CSS and DIV code for above type of layout. I don't want to use tables for this, DIV and CSS only.

In Digg listing the same kind of display can be found. I tried but not able to  make the "username" central align in respect of the avatar image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>Created by: <img src="/images/avatars/prashant.png" alt="" /> Prashant</div>`

and

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align unfortunately is not handled very consistently by some of the older browsers (pre-2005, but then yet again IE6 is still around), but David's answer is correct from the standards view.